# How do I test a controller action in rails that reads a CSV from a remote source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rspec-rails

I want to test a function that looks like this.

```
  def load_template_from_csv
    arr = []
    images = []
    CSV.new(open(params[:a_csv]), headers: true).each_with_index do |row, index|
      # some formating
      res << {row}
    end
    render json: { data: res }
  end
```

I've tried things like

```
it 'tests load_ad_template_from_csv action' do
  account_id = Account.last.id
  get :load_template_from_csv, internal_ad_account_id: ad_account_id, ad_csv: 'test'
  # expect(File).to receive(:open).with('test', headers: true)
  # expect(CSV.stub(:new)).to receive(:new).with('test', headers: true)
  # expect(CSV.stub).to receive(:read).with('test', headers: true)
  # CSV.should_receive(:new).with("file", headers: true)
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

But this doesn't work, am I lacking some basics or is this a hard to test function?

Comment: Define "doesn't work." Are you getting the expected 200 status, but want the items in the comments?

Comment: No, I don't get the 200 status. What I want to understand is what parts I should mock and what I shouldn't.